# Visual no me toma los simbolo escritos en teclado mac

Tags: visual-studio, vscode

tengo un problema al momento de escribir símbolos con teclado en macbook, me sale error, [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]copie y pegué el símbolo desde afuera pero tampoco me funciona, alguna solución?